# achartengine bar chart multi series

Tags: achartengine

I have a Bar Chart that I am using three different series.  All the data shows up correctly but the series are rendering with different widths of the bars for each series.  I can't get the bars from different series to be the same widths.

```
SDFSeries = new XYSeries("Seven Day Forecast"); 
FPSeries = new XYSeries("Forecast Peak"); 
APDSeries = new XYSeries("Actual Peak to Date"); 

XYSeriesRenderer sdfRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer(); 
sdfRenderer.setColor(Color.rgb(90, 152, 253));
sdfRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true); 
sdfRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(18);


XYSeriesRenderer fpRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer(); 
fpRenderer.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 0)); 
fpRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
fpRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(18);

XYSeriesRenderer apdRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer(); 
apdRenderer.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0)); 
apdRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
apdRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(18);

multiRenderer.setXLabels(0); 
multiRenderer.setChartTitle("7 Day Outlook - Maximum Demand"); 
multiRenderer.setXTitle(""); 
multiRenderer.setYTitle("MegaWatts"); 
multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(apdRenderer);         
multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(fpRenderer);
multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(sdfRenderer);
multiRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 10, 65, 10, 15 });  
multiRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
multiRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(30);
multiRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
multiRenderer.setLegendTextSize(20);
multiRenderer.setLegendHeight(40);
multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(.5);
multiRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
multiRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
```

Comment: Sorry I am confused I dont have an answer to a previous question.  I appreciate your chart and it works great I am just stuck on getting the bar widths the same size when using multiple series.  I wish I had enough reputation points to show you what it looks like.

Comment: Yes sorry about that one I accepted the answer as it was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by the fact that the series with one single item display the bar width differently. You have some options:

- Add at least 2 items to each series.
- Use `renderer.setBarWidth()` for the series with one single item.